# Create d.ts containing only directly exported types

Tags: typescript

Goal is to create a TS declaration file that contains a selected set of types.

Let's say I start with this:

```
// main.d.ts
import { Foo } from './other.d.ts'
export { Foo }
```

```
// other.d.ts
export type Foo...

export type Bar...
```

Right now, with `tsc`, what I get is the `main.d.ts` file with all of the deps but I want to not have `Bar` in this build.

Goal:

```
//main.d.ts
import { Foo } from './other.d.ts'
export { Foo }
```

```
// other.d.ts
export type Foo...
```

My end goal is to create a declaration file for publishing and I do not want to include types not explicitly exported in `main.d.ts`. I am open to other approaches.

I have tried API extractor but ran into issues that make it not ideal for the situation.

I essentially want a tree shaking of my types. I do not see a TSConfig option that would allow this. Open to other tools.

Comment: What if you want to use `Bar` in the consumer code? Then, if `Bar` is used somewhere else in the file, you need to go through a bunch of hoops to extract it. Otherwise, it's not possible to use. I think some more context surrounding this package/library would be nice so we know what you're trying to achieve. In my experience, libraries that don't export all the types they use are very frustrating to work with...

Comment: @katniss we have many types file with all the internal stuff. But part of that needs to be exported and shared amongst other projects. Currently we have some files that are common/public and others more internal and we import the public ones into the internal one but frankly its become a mess. It adds about 20 unnecessary files. We could easily make a single `main` export that we would not use internally but would represent what we wish to make public and that would work great - a bit like API extractor ability to do just @public etc - its however buggy and adds other challenges as well.